# How to make a site in malayalam language?

Tags: php, fonts, wysiwyg

I want to create a website. Its contents must be displayed in malayalam language. In admin panel I can edit that malayalam contents of the site also.

How can I do that? Please share your ideas with me. Also help me on this, how to create that kind of a content editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is no different from any other kind of website. You just need to make sure that the character encoding being used supports the characters you need. All modern websites should use a Unicode encoding (such as UTF-8) so that should be taken care of already.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a system like the one you mention is really complex, and takes years of practice to do properly. If you still want to go ahead and code it yourself, you need to learn PHP, MySql, and HTML.

I would recommend, however, that you use a Content Managing System ( CMS ) such as **Wordpress** or drupal. Wordpress is really easy to install and use.

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

Use Unicode encoding

HTML5

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

HTML 4.01

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

xhtml 1.0

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```